# fromJSON %>% as.data.frame failing with multiple levels on select data

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I have a long list of JSON strings I am trying to import and convert to data frames.  Generally, `jsonlite::fromJSON` is working as it should, but about 25% of my JSONs are throwing the error:

`Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 47, 2`

I realize that is because of the different levels in the JSON file, but this seems to be working without problem for the other 75% of my data that have similar structures.

Here is an example to illustrate when it is working and when it is not.

## Not working correctly

```
x1 <- '{\"productCode\":\"DP1.00096.001\",\"sites\":[\"ABBY\",\"BARR\",\"BART\",\"BLAN\",\"BONA\",\"CLBJ\",\"CPER\",\"DCFS\",\"DEJU\",\"DELA\",\"DSNY\",\"GRSM\",\"GUAN\",\"HARV\",\"HEAL\",\"JERC\",\"JORN\",\"KONA\",\"KONZ\",\"LAJA\",\"LENO\",\"MLBS\",\"MOAB\",\"NIWO\",\"NOGP\",\"OAES\",\"ONAQ\",\"ORNL\",\"OSBS\",\"PUUM\",\"RMNP\",\"SCBI\",\"SERC\",\"SJER\",\"SOAP\",\"SRER\",\"STEI\",\"STER\",\"TALL\",\"TEAK\",\"TOOL\",\"TREE\",\"UKFS\",\"UNDE\",\"WOOD\",\"WREF\",\"YELL\"],\"dateRange\":[\"2012-06\",\"2018-07\"],\"documentation\":\"include\",\"packageType\":\"basic\"}'

output1 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(x1)
str(output1)
as.data.frame(output1)
```

## Working correctly

```
x2 <- '{\"productCode\":\"DP1.00095.001\",\"sites\":[\"ABBY\",\"BARR\",\"BART\",\"BLAN\",\"BONA\",\"CLBJ\",\"CPER\",\"DCFS\",\"DEJU\",\"DELA\",\"DSNY\",\"GRSM\",\"GUAN\",\"HARV\",\"HEAL\",\"JERC\",\"JORN\",\"KONA\",\"KONZ\",\"LAJA\",\"LENO\",\"MLBS\",\"MOAB\",\"NIWO\",\"NOGP\",\"OAES\",\"ONAQ\",\"ORNL\",\"OSBS\",\"RMNP\",\"SCBI\",\"SERC\",\"SJER\",\"SOAP\",\"SRER\",\"STEI\",\"STER\",\"TALL\",\"TEAK\",\"TOOL\",\"TREE\",\"UKFS\",\"UNDE\",\"WOOD\",\"WREF\",\"YELL\"],\"dateRange\":[\"2019-01\",\"2019-12\"],\"documentation\":\"include\",\"packageType\":\"basic\"}'

output2 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(x2)
str(output2)
as.data.frame(output2)
```

In both examples, the JSON has an unbalanced structure. The difference is that in `x2` the JSON is able to convert to the data.frame, while in `x1` the JSON output is not. I cannot find a difference in the `str` output nor the actual JSON string to understand where and why it is failing. The structure is identical and I would not expect this operation to fail.

Any help shedding light on why `x1` doesn't work, but `x2` does would be appreciated.  Is there anyway to get `x1` into a working dataframe similar to the `x2` output?

Comment: `x1` has an odd number of `sites` but an even number of `dateRange` values. It cannot determine the correct way to unroll those values. In `x2` you have one column length that is a multiple of the other so each of the sites are turned into a row and the dataRange alternates between the two observed values (which may not be what you really want). Data frames are designed to hold "rectuanguar" data so you should be clear on how you would want to turn those nested values into proper rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with the json per se. It's due to the fact that you are trying to recycle odd and even length vectors. For example:

```r
as.data.frame(list(a = 1, b = 1:2, c = 3:5))
#> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, 
#> : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 3

as.data.frame(list(a = 1, b = 1:2, c = 3:6))
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 1 3
#> 2 1 2 4
#> 3 1 1 5
#> 4 1 2 6
```

The solution to your problem in the case of `output1` would be to add a random string at the end of `output1$sites`:

```r
output1$sites <- c(output1$sites, "")

head(as.data.frame(output1))
#>     productCode sites dateRange documentation packageType
#> 1 DP1.00096.001  ABBY   2012-06       include       basic
#> 2 DP1.00096.001  BARR   2018-07       include       basic
#> 3 DP1.00096.001  BART   2012-06       include       basic
#> 4 DP1.00096.001  BLAN   2018-07       include       basic
#> 5 DP1.00096.001  BONA   2012-06       include       basic
#> 6 DP1.00096.001  CLBJ   2018-07       include       basic
```

Whether it actually makes sense to have your data in this format is not at all clear from the question.

<sup>Created on 2020-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Of course! Thank you for the help- I was looking at this problem in the wrong way and overlooked the basic. Thank you for your guidence